# sql how to return a list in a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new with SQL and I would like to ask for your help concerning a problem that I am facing

the first query query1 that can return 0 or 1 line:

```
with query1 as (select ... from table) select * from query1
```

returns

```
query1 
-
```

or

```
query1 
4567
```

also a second request returning a list:

```
with my_list as (select 'a' from dual union all select 'b' from dual) select * from my_list
```

returns

```
my_list
a
b
```

my problem is the following: I can not condition my first query so that in case query1 returns null then I display my_list.

I tried with this :

```
with my_list as (select 'a' from dual union all select 'b' from dual) 
select case when ( ( select '' from dual /* case when query1 returns nothing */ ) is null ) 
then (select 'a' from dual union all select 'b' from dual) /* my_list */
else (select '' from dual) end 
from my_list;
```

but i have the following error :

> ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

what is this error?

what i want to do is that :

```
with my_list as (select 'a' from dual union all select 'b' from dual),
myquery as (select '' from dual)
select case when ( myquery is null ) 
then (select my_list)
else (select myquery end)
```

so that this query have to return

```
a
b
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `union all`:

```
with query1 as (select ... from table) select * from query1,
     my_list as ( . . . )
select q.*
from query1 q
where ? is not null
union all
select ml.*
from my_list ml
where not exists (select 1 from query1 where ? is not null);
```

`?` is for the column returned by `query1`.

Comment: thanks for this but when I run this query

with query1 as (select '' from dual), my_list as (select 'a' from dual union all select 'b' from dual)
select q.* from query1 q
union all select ml.*
from my_list ml
where not exists (select '' from dual);

it returns null value but I want it to return my_list

Comment: @ccz . . . You just have to fix the `not exists` clause.  It is not clear  what the name of the column is in `query1`, but just check that it doesn't have a `NULL` value.

Comment: the name of the column is param. so i tried with this query but it returns nothing : 
with query1 as (select '' as param from dual), my_list as (select 'a' from dual union all select 'b' from dual)
select q.* from query1 q
union select ml.* from my_list ml
where not exists (select 1 from query1);        
i don't know what is wrong with the query

Comment: Also, `SELECT '' FROM dual` is ***not*** a valid proxy for a query that returns no rows. That returns one row with a null string, which is NOT what you described. Try `SELECT ' ' FROM dual WHERE 1=0` as a query that returns no rows.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help Gordon but I run this query

```
with query1 as (select '' from dual), my_list as (select 'a' from dual union all select 'b' from dual)
select q.* from query1 q
union select ml.* from my_list ml
where not exists (select 1 from query1);
```

it returns null value in stead of returning my_list

Comment: Because one row with a null value is ***not*** the same as no rows.  To "replicate" a query that returns no rows use `SELECT '' FROM dual WHERE 1=0` for Query1.